# Not able to set mapper.readValuemapper.readValue(words, classOf[InboundLocation]) in jackson as showing type mismatch in scala

Tags: scala

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleExample").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(5))

    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

    val kafkaconf = Map(
      "zookeeper.connect" -> "localhost:2181",
      "group.id" -> "test-consumer-group",
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "5000"
    )

    val lines  = KafkaUtils.createStream[Array[Byte], String , DefaultDecoder , StringDecoder](
      sc ,
      kafkaconf,
      Map("testtopickafka" -> 1) ,
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK
    )

    val words : DStream[String]  = lines.flatMap { case (x, y) => y.split(" ") }

       val out :  InboundLocation = mapper.readValue(words, classOf[InboundLocation])
//      val type12 = out.getMessage_id
//      print(type12)





    words.print()
    sc.start()
    sc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Can someone help me to solve this issue as i am Not able to set mapper.readValuemapper.readValue(words, classOf[InboundLocation]) in jackson as showing error type mismatch in scala language

Comment: You can store the words into desired format into Kafka Producer first and then fetch them.

Comment: @VinodChandak words id in DStream[String] , how to store it into differnt format like inputstream or string ? Could you plss help me on this.

Comment: I am talking about storing into kafka, You are fetching it from Kafka. You can store it in kafka into desired format and fetch through it. I have made a sample in which I stored data into JSON format into kafka and I get back into json tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following approach.

```
words.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
    if (rdd.count() > 0) {
       //TODO: Apply your business logic
    }
})
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Hope this helps!